# Translation of "Informatics" and "Computer Science"

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

"*Informatics*" and "*Computer Science*" are two [somehow distinct notions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27573/3023) in English. *Computer science* is usually translated into *informatique* in French.  How would you say *informatics* in French?

Comment: Pour moi, tu pose la question a l'envers. 'Informatics' est l'informatique en général. Tu devrais plutôt demander comment dire 'computer science' qui est un domaine restreint a l’étude des méthodes et systèmes de calcul.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il semble que de plus en plus c'est l'application plus "pratico-pratique" d'*informatique* qui est remplacée, du moins dans les domaines professionnels, par (notamment) *technologie(s) de l'information* ou *technologies de l'information et des communications* (TICs). Informatique se restreint alors à un sens essentiellement identique à *computer science*.

Answer (score 2):

Lors d'une traduction de mémoire, j'ai traduit *informatics and computer science* par *informatique et domaines d'application de l'informatique*. C'est une traduction certes lourdes mais elle permet d'englober les notions congrues aux possibilités de l'informatique, en dehors de la simple science.

Answer (score 1):

La traduction  de *computer science* par *informatique* est  usuelle mais inexacte.

Il faudrait la traduire par *science des ordinateurs*, c'est-à-dire la maîtrise des techniques et le développement des matériels utilisés pour l'enregistrement, le calcul, le transfert et la conservation des données.

Certes, la notion d'*informatique* française englobe la science de ses outils, mais elle renvoie à l'utilisation de ces derniers et aux données qu'ils manipulent :

- transcodage des signaux,
- calculs mathématiques et scientifques,
- analyses et traitements sémantiques,
- bases de données,
- interfaces et écrans
- automates et assistance technique
- langages machines et humains
- messages et interconnexions

sont les grands domaines qui concerne l'*informatique*, avec bien sûr Internet et ses domaines tel le web, le cloud...